# How to build complex query that has join query and subquery using query builder Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good evening my coder friends,

As the title of this Question says, i have a little bit complex mysql query that i am trying to use query builder in Laravel to write it down, but every time i try to write it i stop when reach to the subquery. i will write down the query and also will let you know what the query will do .

```
SELECT 
    brands.name_en as brand_name_en, 
    brands.name_ar as brand_name_ar, 
    brands.brand_url as brand_url, 
    brands.description_ar as description_ar, 
    brands.description_en as description_en, 
    categories.name_en as category_name_en,
    categories.name_ar as category_name_ar     
FROM 
    brands 
    INNER JOIN categories ON brands.category_id = categories.id     
WHERE 
    (brands.status = "1") 
    AND
    (
        brands.id IN (
            SELECT 
                distinct(items.brand_id) 
            FROM 
                items 
            WHERE 
                items.in_stock = "1" 
            GROUP BY 
                (items.brand_id)
        )
    )
```

The query explanation :

I have three tables :

- Brand (id,name,category_id)
- Categories (id,name,brand_id)
- Items (id,brand_id,in_stock,sold_date)

Now i want to do the following :
i want to retrieve (brand name , and the category name ) and sort them based on the highest sales in the last month

This is example on the tables with data in them :

```
Brands Table 
------------
id     name           category_id
1      googleplay     1


Categories Table 
--------------------------
id     name           brand_id
1      cards          1


items Table
-----------
id     brand_id    in_stock       selling_date
1      1           0              null
1      1           1              2017-02-02 04:04:49
```

Been trying for almost 2 days but no luck as its really complicated when it reaches the subquery part .

Really hope to find help from you guys . and let me know if you guys need more explanation please , i might forgot something while writing the questions .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe use `whereInSub`? Also could you show your Eloquent query so far and where you got stuck in it?

Comment: @uruloke sure , give me a min, i am looking to the answer that Mr Javi putted . and to be honest, during my search in the documentation i did not see the `whereInSup` its first time i know that there its exist .

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can just use `whereIn` directly. It uses `whereInSub` underneath if second parameter is a closure.

Comment: @uruloke yes i guess using whereIn will be the door to solve the query, but i am stucked on where  exactly to use it as the code is going crazy atm , the query is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your sql a little, you can make it with inner joins:

```
SELECT brands.name, categories.name
FROM brands 
INNER JOIN categories ON brands.category_id = categories.id 
INNER JOIN items ON categories.id = items.brand_id
WHERE brands.status = 1 AND items.in_stock = 1
```

Translating this to Laravel is simple:

```
\DB::table('brands')
    ->join('categories', 'brands.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->join('items', 'brands.id', '=', 'items.brand_id')
    ->select('brands.name as brand', 'categories.name as category')
    ->where('brands.status', 1)
    ->where('items.in_stock', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually speaking, How about we select the items from the item tables for the last month, sort them and fetch the brand and category via a join on that.

It can be written in a single query as follows:

```
DB::table('items')
    ->join('brands', 'items.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
    ->join('categories', 'brands.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->select('brands.name as brand', 'categories.name as category')
    ->where('brands.status', 1) // as per your query
    ->whereRaw(YEAR(items.selling_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) // year condition
    ->whereRaw(MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) // last month condition
    ->orderBy('items.in_stock', 'desc') // orderBy the sales
    ->distinct() // Since you only require brand names and category names, choosing distinct will avoid the need of the GROUP BY eliminating the multiple occurances of a brand in the items table
    ->get()
```

I haven't tried running this query, but hope it helps. If I have misunderstood the question feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thank you Lav, i am tweaking your code to match with the data i want, will let you know what happens . as me also checking Javi answer as well.

Comment: I am still tweaking , got confused a bit from the query as i am not getting the correct results . but i am sure your code is so close to what i need

Comment: Your answer was so close to what i was looking for, the query is really complex so i had to take a the time part where i get the data sorted based on the date! . with that been said , yes your answer is so close.  thank you